# Codigo Correlativo Java

Tags: java

quisiera saber como generar un codigo correlativo con este formato "30200-01" el numero 30200 es un codigo que ya esta establecido en la base de datos, el numero 01 es un numero que cada vez que genere un documento aumente, "30200-01" "30200-02" "30200-03" y asi sucesivamente, pero cada vez que ingreso me sale asi: "30200-1" sin el cero. Este es el codigo que estoy implementando:
Este metodo es para obtener el codigo "30200" ya establecido en la base de datos:

```
 void generarSerieDocumental(String centroCosto){
            Connection cn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstm = null;
            ResultSet rs = null;
            try {
                cn = new MySqlConexion().getConectar();
                String sql = "SELECT c_ccosto FROM FCCOSTO WHERE x_ccosto = ?";
                pstm = cn.prepareStatement(sql);
                pstm.setString(1, centroCosto);
                rs = pstm.executeQuery();
                while(rs.next()){
                    txtSerieDocumental.setText(rs.getString("c_ccosto"));
                }
            } 
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                try {
                    if (rs != null)
                        rs.close();
                    if (pstm != null)
                        pstm.close();
                    if (cn != null)
                        cn.close();
                } 
                catch (Exception e2) {
                    e2.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Este evento boton agregar, es para que cada vez le doy click al boton agregar, el codigo se muestre en una tabla y se vaya generando el codigo "30200-01" "30200-02" y asi sucesivamente cuando haga click en el boton

```
protected void btnAgregarActionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
        DefaultTableModel model = (DefaultTableModel) tbSerieDocumental.getModel();
        String codigo = txtSerieDocumental.getText();
        int Item = tbSerieDocumental.getRowCount() + 1;
        String codigoSerial = codigo+"-"+Item;
        Object fila[]={codigoSerial,"","",""};
        model.addRow(fila);
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema pasa por creer que 01 es un numero, muy por el contrario es una cadena de texto.

Tu lo que vas a tener que hacer es lo siguiente

```
int Item = tbSerieDocumental.getRowCount() + 1;
if(Item < 10){
   String codigoSerial = codigo+"-0"+Item;
}else{
   String codigoSerial = codigo+"-"+Item;
}
```

Agregue el `if(Item < 10){` para que cuando el numero sea mayor a 9, no anteponga el 0, si no el numero que corresponde.

Comment: El codigo me aparece en la tabla con espacios de esta manera: "30200 - 01" como haría para quitar esos espacios

Comment: @BrunoTorres le quite el espacio al string. `codigo+"-0"+Item;` ai queda bien

Comment: El espacio ahora esta asi: "30200 -01"

Comment: ese espacio esta donde tienes definida tu variable codigo, revisalo que esta `codigo = "30200" ` y no `codigo = "30200 " `

Comment: ese codigo viene de la base de datos

Comment: entonces verifica que en la base de datos no este con espacio

Comment: el codigo esta bien en la base de datos

Answer (score 3):

Hay una forma de formatear ese tipo de cadenas que viene muy bien para hacer el padding de ceros que quieres y te evitar el `if/else`. Quedaría así:

```
String codigoSerial = String.format("%s-%02d", codigo, Item);
```

Con eso indicas que quieres que el número tenga 2 dígitos rellenando de ceros por la izquierda si hace falta.

Comment: Me parece que esta es la respuesta correcta! @BrunoTorres

Comment: y entonces por qué elegiste la otra @brunotorres?

Comment: @Chochos La mía la hice después de que la aceptara. Símplemente la puse para que otros puedan aprovecharlo.